# Firebase - How to retrieve the ID of a database item?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've set up a simple database which holds questions and answers to those questions. Pretty simple, just 5 strings and that's it. Here's the code:

```
questions
 -KbFaJVwP1HKu-rHfrjT
     ans1: 
        "test"
     ans2: 
        "1"
     ans3: 
        "2"
     ans4: 
        "3"
     question: 
        "Testing"
 -KbFlP8A08y2k4Vp1XET
     ans1: 
        "test"
     ans2: 
        "test2"
     ans3: 
        "test3"
     ans4: 
        "test4"
     question: 
        "Testing"
```

I've submitted two entries just to test it out, but what I'm wondering is how do I return the IDs of these questions? I need a unique identifier, which in these cases is *KbFaJVwP1HKu-rHfrjT* and *KbFlP8A08y2k4Vp1XET*, but using the getKey method, I'm getting the "question" as a result, because it is set as a primary key.

How do I work around this issue? Is my database set up improperly?

Answer (score 2):

If you get `question` when calling `getKey()`, you can iterate through the children with:

```
for( DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
    String childKey = child.getKey();
    ...
}
```

This will loop twice, where `childKey` will be *-KbFaJVwP1HKu-rHfrjT* and *-KbFlP8A08y2k4Vp1XET*

Comment: I just got two questions:

What is `dataSnapshot` and is child supposed to be the value that returns `question`?

I know I'm asking too much, but could you post the whole sample code? Thanks for your response!

Comment: The code is general because I don't have any piece of your code to adjust mine. `dataSnapshot` is the snapshot on which you called `getKey()` and got _question_. `child` will be the snapshot one level lower where `getKey()` returns the UIDs